# Website form being automatically sent (PHP script firing automatically)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I recently started managing a site on SiteGround and something weird is happening with my "Contact Us" form that I cannot figure out. Everyday, typically at 1PM Eastern time, I get an email letting me know that the "Contact Us" form was filled out, but there is no information from the form.

The page has a few simple text inputs and a radio button, the form validation is handled by javascript so if an input is left blank it won't submit the form. When everything is validated the information is sent via AJAX and a simple PHP script sends an email (PHP's mail() function), as well as enters the info into a DB.

So everyday at 1PM, usually on the dot, I get an email with no information. The form has been tested and info displays when it gets entered correctly. **I do not know what could be causing this! I know I can prevent the email and DB entry with some simple variable checking in the PHP script but I would like to know why this is happening in the first place, does anyone have any ideas?**

I can post some code but its all basic HTML, one AJAX jquery call, and about 10 lines of php to send the email.

Comment: Check your server access logs, and you can see where the page is being accessed from.

Comment: Possibly a bot spidering your site. Have you got any analytics on the site? Or IP tracking on the user who completed the form? You should also have server-side validation. JS validation is a courtesy to the user, server-side is business critical.

Comment: Make sure your php sendmail script is checking for post submit before running code.

Comment: How about adding recaptcha?

Comment: Spider Bot was the only thing coming to mind but I don't know enough about them myself to suggest that. I am adding server-side validation right now and I use google analytics. I will check out my access logs but I am getting a submission even when google analytics says 0 visitors. Thank you all for the quick responses. I may have lost points on this question but I had to ask, I need to know why before I fix things lol!

Comment: @KaseyE google analytics would probably not count the google analytics crawler as a visit, and the google analytics crawler does try submitting forms. Firstly you need to add server-side validation, and secondly you can add a `Disallow: /path` entry in your `robots.txt` for that path and hope crawlers respect it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan suggestion of server-side validation cannot be emphasized enough. It's entirely possible that a bot which cannot parse or run JavaScript is hitting your page and submitting your form. In this case your JavaScript validation is moot which why it is absolutely critical that you do server side validation. To verify this, open your page in chrome, open the dev tools, select the `Disable JavaScript` option and try submitting your form. If it works, you've found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once, couldn't come up with an explanation but I do have a solution : simply validate for empty values before calling your mail function. Eg.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['txtEmail']) && !empty($_POST['txtMessage'])) mail(...);
```

Comment: yeah that's what i ended up doing, I was just trying to find that elusive explanation first. oh well

Comment: I believe @Rory McCrossan has the answer with the spider bots.